# Как разделить текстовый файл?

Tags: delphi

Нужна быстрая процедура для разделения текстового файла на отдельные файлы в Delphi XE4.

Имеется файл .txt в 300 000 строк, пример:

> Название организации: Atk
>   Род занятий: Строительство
>   Тип: Подрядчик

Как разделить этот файл на три текстовых файла, чтобы:
В первом файле были все строки  -  "Название организации: и тут текст"
Во втором файле были все строки -  "Род занятий: и тут текст"
В третьем файле были все строки -  "Тип: и тут текст"

Comment: Что конкретно вас интересует? Алгоритм или решение??

Comment: Мне нужен алгоритм при котором, при нажатии на кнопку - программа разделила базу на три файла. То есть решение как я указала выше. Нуждаюсь в помощи :(.

Comment: Главное в этом "алгоритме", как я понимаю, - нажатие на кнопку.

Comment: Да просто нажать на кнопку. Было бы неплохо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
begin

  ЦИКЛ: читаем строку из файла пока файл не закончится;

  if строка_начинается_с "Название организации"
     then записать в первый файл;
     else         
  if строка_начинается_с "Род занятий"
     then записать во второй файл;
     else        
  if строка_начинается_с "Тип"
     then записать в третий файл;        

  КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА
  удалить исходный файл (или не удалять, по настроению)
end;
```

Comment: Да но самой процедуры нет. Я не опытная еще в Delphi :(. Подскажите полный код ?

Comment: +1 за то что не даете готовый код. Вместо `строка == ` лучше сделать `строка_начинается_с`. А вместо `continue` лучше просто else

Comment: Неопытная, но нахальная. Почитайте книжку.

Comment: Да не нахальная я, ребята :). Просто эти отчеты на работе утомляют. Не хочу в ручную обрабатывать. Потому и за помощью обратилась.

Comment: @Татьяна грань между "помогите научиться" и "сделайте мне" достаточно тонкая. Пока что вы уверенно ее пересекаете такими вопросами и за это их заслуженно минусуют.

Comment: Kromster, Я не понимаю почему такая реакция ?. Я ваше мнение уважаю, никакую грань я не пересекаю. Я понимаю что Вы все опытные и все такое. Но задав просто вопрос я получаю только ответ, в котором вы указываете на мою неопытность. Тогда зачем вообще вы пишите в мою тему? Если не хотите помочь ?. Просто из за того что хотите показать какой вы умный ?. Ну тогда желаю удачи. Можете ставить минусы сколько хотите, найдутся люди - которые более адекватно и проще будут реагировать на мои вопросы.

Comment: @Татьяна Вам же сказали что вы не чувствуете грани между "помогите" и "сделайте"! И конкретно в вашем случае все что мы можем сделать что бы вам помочь так это "сделать за вас"! Учиться , как я вижу, вы не собираетесь и просите готовый код, хотя я вам выложил уже готовый алгоритм который осталось переписать нужным вам языком! Потратьте один - три вечера что бы разобраться в базовых структурах языка и 70 процентов вопросов отпадут

Comment: JVic, К Вам я никаких претензий не имею. Вы помогли мне настолько насколько смогли. За это я поставила плюсик. Заставлять вас делать за меня код я не имею права. От себя вам человеческое спасибо. Все равно код я не смогу написать.

Comment: @Татьяна какая реакция вам непонятна, то что минусуют и закрывают, или то что объясняют почему? Грань вы пересекаете постоянно - у вас 80% вопросов изначально сформулированы как "напишите за меня весь код". В ваши вопросы я пишу с желанием помочь (правками, ответами, советами, объяснениями). Не гневайтесь )

Comment: Kromster. Нет у меня никакого гнева. Вашу позицию поняла и приняла. Сказать больше нечего, хорошего дня.